Proof of Orthonormal basis for $L_2(\mathbb R)$ by Hermite Polynomials
Consider $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as an Hilbert space with inner product $(\cdot ,\cdot)$. Define
$$\psi_n(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}H_n(x),$$
where $H_n(x)$ is the Hermite Polynomials. How do you show that $\{\psi_n(x)\}$ is a orthogonal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? (We can make it orthonormal by normalize it).
There is a proof here:
Orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by Hermite Polynomials, but I have a question:

Why $A_{n,m(n)}\to −\int f(x)^2e^{−x^2}dx$ hold?

I understand that $\int_\mathbb R P_{n,m(n)}(x)f(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=0$, but why $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_\mathbb R P_{n,m(n)}(x)\cdot I_{[supp(g_n)]}(x)f(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx= 0$?
There is also a proof here: The complete orthonormal basis on $L^2(-\infty,+\infty)$ about Hermite polynomials., but I have little knowledge of fourier transformation. I want a more basic solution.
Many thanks in advance!

Presumably the problem is not to show that the Hermite functions $(\psi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are orthogonal, but to show that the span of the Hermite functions is dense in $L^2$:
The span of the Hermite functions is the same as
$$
V := \{ f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}): \exists  \text{polynomial} \ p  : \forall x \in \mathbb{R}:  f(x)  =\exp (-x^2/2) \cdot p (x) \}.
$$
Using the series expansion of $\exp$ it is not terribly difficult to show that for $p \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $f_p \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$
f_p (x) := \exp (i px) \exp ( -x^2/2)
$$
is in $\overline{V}$.
To show that $V$ is dense, it is sufficient to show that $\forall f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$:
$$
\big( \forall v \in \bar V : \langle f, v \rangle = 0 \big) \Rightarrow f =0.
$$
Let $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ with $ \forall v \in \bar V : \langle f, v \rangle = 0 $.
Then in particular for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \exp (i px ) f(x) \exp( -x^2/2) dx=0.
$$
Note that $x \mapsto  f(x) \exp( -x^2/2) \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}) \cap L^1 (\mathbb{R})$, because of Hölders inequality and since $x \mapsto  \exp( -x^2/2) \in L^\infty (\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
Using the below lemma it follows, that $x \mapsto f(x) \exp( -x^2/2)  =0$ which in turn implies that $f =0$.
(The following lemma actually shows that the Fourier transform is injective by elementary means):

Lemma: Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ with $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \exp (i px ) f(x)dx=0.
$$ Then $f =0$.

Proof:
Let $a \in (0, \infty)$
Define the function $k \in  L^1(\mathbb{R}) $ by $k(x):= (ax)^{-2} \sin^2 (ax)$.
Define $\operatorname{tri} \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ by
$$
\operatorname{tri} (x) := \begin{cases}
1- |x| \quad \text{if } |x| <1, \\
0 \quad \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ :
$$
\hat k (x) := \int_\mathbb{R} \exp ( -ipx) k(p) dp = a^{-1} \operatorname{tri}\left( \frac{x}{2\pi a} \right).
$$
This is a common integral (usually arising as a Fourier transform) see for example the answer by Andy Walls here alternatively it can also be derived by contour integration.
Therefore for all $ y \in \mathbb{R}$ using Fubinis Theorem for the third equality:
$$
\begin{split}
\langle \hat k  f, x \mapsto \exp(iyx) \rangle_{L^2([-2\pi a, 2\pi a])}&= 
\int_\mathbb{R} \exp (- iyx ) \hat k (x) f(x) dx\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \exp ( -i p x) k(p) dp \exp (-i yx ) f(x) dx \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R}  k(p)  \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp (-i (y+p)x ) f(x) dx}_{=0} dp\\
&=0.
\end{split}
$$
Since the trigenometric system is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([-2\pi a, 2\pi a ])$ it follows that $\hat k f = 0$, which in turn implies, that $f=0$ on say $[-\pi a , \pi a]$. By varying $a$ we obtain $f=0$.

If you wish to avoid Fourier analysis completely, consider this outline of an alternative argument that is perhaps more physically intuitive.
Suppose $f$ is orthogonal to all Hermite functions. We wish to show $f$ is zero, ie. $||f||_{L^2}$ is arbitrarily small.
Step 1. We claim that $f$ is orthogonal to all dilates of the Gaussian.
Proof. Consider the dilated Gaussian $ G(a,x)= e^{- ax^2}$ which is in $L^2$ for all real $a>0$, and in fact for all complex $a$ satisfying $Re(a)>0$.
Note that the inner-product  integral
$I(a)=< f(x), G(a,x)> =\int _x f(x) e^{-a x^2} dx $
is also analytic in the complex variable $a$ on that region. All its derivatives vanish at $a=1$, because $D_a^kI(a)_{a=1} = <f(x),(- x^2)^k G(1,x) >$  and $x^{2k} G(1,x)$  is in the linear span of the Hermite functions.
Thus $I(a) $ vanishes for all $a>0$. In other words, $f$ is orthogonal to the family of all dilates of the centered Gaussian.
Step 2. A similar argument shows that all translates of the dilated Gaussian of the form $G(a, x-b)$ also have the property that  they are orthogonal to $f$. (because derivatives with respect to $b$ are polynomials times Gaussians.)
Let $S$ be the space  spanned by   all such dilated translated Gaussians.  We know $f\perp S$.
Step 3.  It suffices now to prove that $S$ is dense in $L^2$.
Consider this  auxiliary subspace $\tilde S$ of $L^2$: the compactly supported continuous functions.  We claim that every  $\tilde f\in \tilde S $ can be approximated arbitrarily well in $L^2$ by an element of $S$.
Rather than proving this by brute force*, for brevity we'll  just invoke a general result (Stone's version of the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem).
The functions in $S$ are closed under addition and multiplication (i.e., $S$ is an algebra) and the functions in $S$ clearly separate points. Consider any compact interval. Note that constant functions can be approximated arbitrarily well on this interval in uniform norm by elements of $S$ (by letting $a\to 0$).  Stone's generalization of the Weierstrass approximation theorem  implies that we can approximate $\tilde f$  arbitrarily well in uniform norm by an element of $S$, hence also in the $L^2$ norm.
*The brute force method would involve approximating piece-wise linear functions by linear combinations of elements of $S$. This could be done by e.g. convolving  with a Gaussian approximate identity and then approximating the convolution integral with a discrete sum. This line of reasoning is I believe how Weierstrass originally proved his version of the approximation theorem.
